# Is there a way to unit test an AWS EventBridge event pattern?

Tags: aws-event-bridge

I would like to unit test my EventBridge event patterns against a few event shapes in Typescript.

For example, this event:

```json
{
  "version": "0",
  "id": "22222222-dcba-4444-dcba-333333333333",
  "detail-type": "Access Analyzer Finding",
  "source": "aws.access-analyzer",
  "account": "123456789012",
  "time": "2019-11-21T01:22:33Z",
  "region": "us-west-2",
  "resources": ["arn:aws:access-analyzer:us-west-2:123456789012:analyzer/MyAnalyzer"],
  "detail": {
    "version": "1.0",
    "accountId": "123456789012",
    "region": "us-west-2",
    "isDeleted": false,
    "id": "bbbbaaaa-abcd-1111-abcd-666666666666",
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "resourceType": "AWS::S3::Bucket",
    "resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
    "createdAt": "2019-11-20T04:58:50Z",
    "analyzedAt": "2019-11-21T01:22:22Z",
    "updatedAt": "2019-11-21T01:14:07Z",
    "principal": {
      "AWS": "999988887777"
    },
    "action": ["s3:GetObject"],
    "condition": {},
    "isPublic": false
  }
}
```

will trigger this event pattern:

```
{
  "source": ["aws.access-analyzer"],
  "detail-type": ["Access Analyzer Finding"]
}
```

So I would like to write a unit test along the lines of:

```js
describe('EventPattern', () => {
  let eventPattern;

  beforeAll(() => {
    eventPattern = {
      "source": ["aws.access-analyzer"],
      "detail-type": ["Access Analyzer Finding"]
    }
  });

  it('should match a valid event', () => {
    expect(EventBridgeEmulator.evaluate(eventPattern, event)).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Where `EventBridgeEmulator.evaluate(eventPattern, event)` is the missing piece.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your development environment and ci/cd pipeline has access to AWS, you can write unit tests with the TestEventPattern API: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/APIReference/API_TestEventPattern.html

```js
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';

const eventbridge = new AWS.EventBridge({ region: 'us-west-2' });

describe("EventPattern", () => {
  let eventPattern;

  beforeAll(() => {
    eventPattern = {
      source: ["aws.access-analyzer"],
      "detail-type": ["Access Analyzer Finding"],
    };
  });

  it("should match a valid event", () => {
    const params = {
      EventPattern: JSON.stringify(eventPattern),
      Event: JSON.stringify(event),
    };

    const request = await eventbridge.testEventPattern(params).promise();
    expect(request.Result).toBe(true);
  });
});
```